# Insect identification by example

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Upstate NY USA here.

I am trying to identify the type of insect that this is:

**Top-side:**

[image]

**Bottom-side:**

[image]

Is this a cockroach? If so what type/sub-species might it be? If not, what other type of bug have I stumbled across here?

Comment: Size approximations would be helpful. It's not a cockroach by the looks of it; just a harmless beetle of some sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is some species of Ground Beetle (family **Carabidae**); the trochanter of the hind leg (just before and somewhat overlapping the femur) and the threadlike antennae helps point to that group.  The book *The beetles of northeastern North America* by N. M. Downie and Ross H. Arnett (Sandhill Crane Press 1996; now out of print but in at least some libraries) may help with a species identification (fair warning: the keys are not profusely illustrated).